# Why is ScyPy's integration called "quad"?

Tags: python, scipy, terminology

Fairly self explanatory - According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html), the general purpose integration method is "quad". The naming convention continues for double integration (dblquad), triple integration (tplquad) etc.

As far as I'm aware there is no mathematical connection between integration and the term "quad". so why does scipy name these methods as such?

Comment: [Numerical Integration: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#History)

Answer (score 3):

Via [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) (link mine):

> Integrate func from a to b (possibly infinite interval) using a technique from the Fortran library [QUADPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUADPACK).

Further, [Wikipedia on numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration):

> his article focuses on calculation of definite integrals. The term *numerical quadrature* (often abbreviated to **quadrature**) is more or less a synonym for numerical integration, especially as applied to one-dimensional integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The term orginates from a method of approximating the area under a curve. The curve is approximated by a number of quadrilateral strips, the more strips the closer the approximation. Depending on the method used the strips could be rectangles or more general quadrilaterals. The areas of the individual strips are calculated then summed.

Some examples show just some of the methods..

[image]

[Image from here which has a good explaination](https://mathsmadeeasy.co.uk/gcse-maths-revision/area-under-a-graph-revision/)

[image]

[image]

[Last 2 images from here which again has a good explanation](http://www.technologyuk.net/mathematics/integral-calculus/area-under-curve.shtml)

Nowadays there are many more complex versions of numerical integration but they all use the historically derived term **quadrature** which comes from the above methods.